# Can't get JSON Structs to work Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, openweathermap

I am trying to make a weather app using the OpenWeatherMap API, in Swift 4, I want to get the 5 day forecast.  I have a fully working app with the current forecast so far, using Openweathermaps different API, using the same methods and structs.  But when I go to make a new bunch of structs for my new ViewController, it fills the screen with multiple errors, such as :
'Type 'MyForecast' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'' and:
 ''Sys' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context' and:
 'Invalid redeclaration of 'Sys''.

Thanks in advance.

Code Below:

Structs:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

//JSON Structs below

struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double?
}

struct Weather: Decodable {
    var id : Int?
    var main, description, icon : String?

}

struct Sys: Decodable {
    let pod: Bool?
}

struct Main: Decodable {

    let temp, temp_min, temp_max, sea_level, grnd_level, temp_kf : Double?
    let pressure, humidity : Int?
}

struct Wind: Decodable {
    let speed : Double?
    let deg: Int?
}

struct Clouds: Decodable {
    let all: String?
}

struct MyForecast : Decodable {
    let cod, dnt: Int?
    let message : Double?
    let name : String?
    let coord : Coordinate?
    let id : Int?
    let sys : Sys?
    let main: Main?
    let wind: Wind?
    let weather: [Weather]?
    let clouds: Clouds?
}
```

View Controller Code:

```
class ForecastViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func loadWeather() {


            guard let APIUrl = URL (string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Crowland,uk&APPID=***API***KEY***&units=metric") else { return }
            //API KEY

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }


            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            //Decoder

                do {

                    let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyForecast.self, from: data)

                    if (self.testLabel != nil)
                    {
                    if let test =  (weatherData.weather?.first?.main) { //using .first because Weather is stored in an array
                        print(test)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.testLabel.text! = String (test)
                            }
                        }
                    }


            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()

}

}
```

Comment: As far as I read the API docs of OpenWeatherMap, the result structures of Current Weather and 5 Days Forecast are different. You cannot use _the same struct_.

Comment: I have managed to rid of all the errors mentioned above, but now I get the error 'The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.', which is what I think you mentioned, about the Structs being different for current weather and the 5 days forecast. I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: For the last time `OpenWeatherMap` sends always very reliable data, all optionals in the structs are pointless. If you want to use multiple structs with the same name you have to declare them **inside** different classes/structs.

Comment: http://jsoncafe.com/ try to use this for converting json data into model codable structs